# Converting bytearray to base64 pdf not (always) showing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, base64

So I'm saving a pdf file as a bytearray in the database and when I need it, I'll download it and convert it to a base64 string in my front end and format it properly.

Sometimes this is showing, but sometimes it doesn't and I can't figure out why, or find a better way to tackle this.

[image: Example]

My view:

```
@{
    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.PdfAsBinary);
    var pdfSrc = String.Format("data:application/pdf;base64,{0}", base64);
}
<embed src="@pdfSrc" type="application/pdf" />
```

This is my factory and how I store the pdf in the database:

```
byte[] image = File.ReadAllBytes(currentFileLocation);
_formerRepository.InsertFormerFileAsBinary(requestId, image);
```

This is the InsertFormerFileAsBinary method handling the database save:

```
public void InsertFormerFileAsBinary (int requestId, byte[] file)
{
    using (var context = new ACSWEntities())
    {
        context.ACSW_UpdateFormerRequestPdfAsBinary(requestId, file);
    }
}
```

The outcome looks like a perfectly structured base64 string (tag has a total of 89107(!) characters:

```
<embed src="data:application/pdf;base64,SUkqAEQEAQCAACBQOCQWDQeEQmFQuGQ2HQ+IRGJROKRWLReMRmNRuOR2PR+QSGRSOSSWTSeUSmVSuWS2XS+YTGZTOaTWbTecTmdTu......BCURIXC8MnwgULgGfgDxOgZ/==" type="application/pdf" />
```

Comment: Read [ask] and define "working". What do you expect to happen and what actually happens? Also, why don't you use an iframe with a request to a dedicated binary download action, so you won't bloat your HTML?

Comment: Updated it as much as currently possible. Since my Firefox browser currently has issues and I can't solve it, it's hard to show further details I guess. And I'm not sure what you mean with the dedicated binary download action. When and how will this happen?